# how to change value of dictionary of dictionary effectively and dynamically

Tags: ios, swift

If I have a dictionary "dic" like this:

```
{
    "a": {
           "b": Any
         }
    "c": {
           "d": Any 
         }
}
```

If I want to change the value of key "b", I know I can do it like this:

```
dic["a"]["b"] = somethingNew
```

But If the key path is varible, how can I change the value according to the key path? is there some api like this:

```
dic.updateValueByKeyPath(path: ["a", "b"], updateValue: somethingNew)
```

Or the idea to achieve this purpose , thanks ~

Comment: Actually you cannot do `dic["a"]["b"] = somethingNew`

Comment: What do you mean with `But If the key path is varible` ?

Comment: @LucaD'Alberti  I mean the key path could be ["a"]["b"] or ["c"]["d"], it is a varible

Comment: But in this case what do you want to change? I don't understand: you want to change the ["a"]["b"] value and then the keyPath could be ["c"]["d"]...there isn't any logic behind this. Find the logic first and then you can implement it simply

Comment: Also try to test things out in playground. It's especially useful for cases like this. You'll find out `dic["a"]["b"] = somethingNew` won't work like vadian mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently answered a Q&A that wanted to *remove* (rather than update) a nested value in a dictionary of nested dictionaries.

- [Remove nested key from dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40267523/4573247)

We can use a similar approach here: using a recursive method which visits your given key path by repeatedly attempting conversions of (sub-)dictionary values to `[Key: Any]` dictionaries themselves. The only restriction here is that the `Key` types much be the same for all dictionaries within the nested dictionary.

#### Implementation

Recursive "core" function `updateValue(_:, inDict:, forKeyPath:)` and public `updateValue(_:, forKeyPath:)` method form key paths on for `[Key]` (e.g. `["a", "b"]` applied to your example):

```
/* general "key path" extension */
public extension Dictionary {

    public mutating func updateValue(_ value: Value, forKeyPath keyPath: [Key])
        -> Value? {
        let (valInd, newDict) = updateValue(value, inDict: self, 
            forKeyPath: Array(keyPath.reversed()))
        if let dict = newDict as? [Key: Value] { self = dict }
        return valInd
    }

    fileprivate func updateValue(_ value: Value, inDict dict: [Key: Any], 
        forKeyPath keyPath: [Key]) -> (Value?, [Key: Any]) {
        guard let key = keyPath.last else { return (value, dict) }

        var dict = dict

        if keyPath.count > 1, let subDict = dict[key] as? [Key: Any] {
            let (val, newSubDict) = updateValue(value, inDict: subDict, 
                forKeyPath: Array(keyPath.dropLast()))
            dict[key] = newSubDict
            return (val, dict)
        }

        let val = dict.updateValue(value, forKey: key) as? Value
        return (val, dict)
    }
}
```

Less general public `updateValue(_:, forKeyPath:)` method (using the core function above) for keys that conforms to `ExpressibleByStringLiteral`; key paths on form `my.key.path` (e.g. `"a.b"` applied to your example):

```
/* String literal specific "key path" extension */
public extension Dictionary where Key: ExpressibleByStringLiteral { 

    public mutating func updateValue(_ value: Value, forKeyPath keyPath: String) 
        -> Value? {
        let keyPathArr = keyPath.components(separatedBy: ".")
            .reversed().flatMap { $0 as? Key }
        if keyPathArr.isEmpty { return self.updateValue(value, forKey: "") }

        let (valInd, newDict) = updateValue(value, 
            inDict: self, forKeyPath:keyPathArr)
        if let dict = newDict as? [Key: Value] { self = dict }
        return valInd
    }
}
```

#### Example usage

We'll apply the methods above to the example from the linked thread.

```
var dict: [String: Any] = [
    "countries": [
        "japan": [
            "capital": [
                "name": "tokyo",
                "lat": "35.6895",
                "lon": "139.6917"
            ],
            "language": "japanese"
        ]
    ],
    "airports": [
        "germany": ["FRA", "MUC", "HAM", "TXL"]
    ]
]
```

Using the `ExpressibleByStringLiteral` key path method to update the value of an existing key-value pair:

```
if let oldValue = dict.updateValue("nihongo", 
    forKeyPath: "countries.japan.language") {
    print("Removed old value: ", oldValue)
}
else {
    print("Added new key-value pair")
}
print(dict) 
/*  Removed old value:  japanese    

    [
        "countries": [
            "japan": [
                "capital": [
                    "name": "tokyo", 
                    "lon": "139.6917"
                    ], 
                "language": "nihongo"
            ]
        ], 
        "airports": [
            "germany": ["FRA", "MUC", "HAM", "TXL"]
        ]
    ] */
```

The same method used to add a new key-value pair at a given key path dictionary:

```
if let oldValue = dict.updateValue("asia", 
    forKeyPath: "countries.japan.continent") {
    print("Removed old value: ", oldValue)
}
else {
    print("Added new key-value pair")
}
print(dict) 
/*  Added new key-value pair    

    [
        "countries": [
            "japan": [
                "capital": [
                    "name": "tokyo", 
                    "lon": "139.6917"
                    ], 
                "language": "nihongo",
                "continent": "asia"
            ]
        ], 
        "airports": [
            "germany": ["FRA", "MUC", "HAM", "TXL"]
        ]
    ] */
```

We would get the same result as in the examples above if we used the general `[Key]` as key path method instead of the `ExpressibleByStringLiteral` one used above. Using the former, the calls would be changed into:

```
... = dict.updateValue("nihongo", 
      forKeyPath: ["countries", "japan", "language"]

... = dict.updateValue("asia", 
      forKeyPath: ["countries", "japan", "continent"]
```

Finally note that a call to `updateValue` using the `[Key]` as key path method will return `nil` also in case of an empty array being passed as argument (`[]`). This could possibly be changed to a throwing case, as a `nil` return above should tell us that a new key-value pair was added (as inspired by [the `updateValue(_:, forKey:)` method](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/dictionary/1539001-updatevalue) in stdlib).

---

**Performance?**

The methods above will make use of some (sub-)dictionary copying along the way, but unless you're working with huge dictionaries, this shouldn't be an issue. Anyhow, no need to worry about performance until a profiler tells you have a bottleneck.