# Updating portions of data using Locksmith Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

Say I originally stored some data using Locksmith via:

```
                    do
                    {

                        try Locksmith.saveData(data: ["a": a_data, "b":b_data, "c":c_data, "d":d_data], forUserAccount: "user") //store it
                        print("Data successfully Saved.")
                    } catch ...
```

Would it be possible to go back later on and only update a specific field without overwriting existing data stored in the keychain. For instance, if I had originally stored a,b,c and d. When i update field b with:

```
try Locksmith.updateData(["b": "new"], forUserAccount: "user")
```

Will I overwrite a,b,c,d with only new data (i.e. a,b,c,d -> new_b) or will Locksmiths update function only update the specific field. I should mention that I have tried to find the answer within the documentation but cannot seem to find it, unless I have overlooked it. In that case, I apologize. Nevertheless, any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the documentation is quite clear that the available static `Locksmith.updateData(_:, forUserAccount:)` method *replaces* any given data for the user. I quote from [matthewpalmer/Locksmith](https://github.com/matthewpalmer/Locksmith) [**emphasis mine**]

> ***Update data***
>
> as well as **replacing existing data**, this writes data to the
>   keychain if it does not exist already
>
> ```
> try Locksmith.updateData(["some key": "another value"], 
>                          forUserAccount: "myUserAccount")
> ```

We can verify this statement by looking at on the following non-failing test ([Locksmith/Tests/LocksmithTests.swift](https://github.com/matthewpalmer/Locksmith/blob/master/Tests/LocksmithTests.swift)):

```
// ....

let userAccount = "myUser"

func testStaticMethods() {
    // ...    

    let otherData: TestingDictionaryType = ["something": "way different"]

    // ...

    let updatedData = ["this update": "brings the ruckus"]
    try! Locksmith.updateData(data: updatedData, forUserAccount: userAccount, inService: service)

    let loaded3 = Locksmith.loadDataForUserAccount(userAccount: userAccount, inService: service)! as! TestingDictionaryType

    // NOTE: this assert checks that the loaded data equals the 
    //       updated data (_not_ 'otherData' updated by 'updatedData')
    XCTAssertEqual(loaded3, updatedData)

    // ...
}
```

where the static `Locksmith.updateData(_:, forUserAccount:)` method clearly *replaces* the data of a given user account.

---

If you'd like to simply add sub-data to existing data of a user, you could implement this yourself:

1. Read data for a given user account

   ```
   let currentData = Locksmith.loadDataForUserAccount(userAccount: userAccount)
   ```
2. Update the data dictionary manually. There exists numerous SO threads explaining this step, see e.g.

   - [how to change value of dictionary of dictionary effectively and dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40374510/how-to-change-value-of-dictionary-of-dictionary-effectively-and-dynamically/40381154#40381154)
3. User the `Locksmith.saveData(_:, forUserAccount:)` static method to save your updated data for the given user account.

Comment: Thank for the simple explanation!

Comment: @RobertHerrera happy to help!