# Swift 4: Find value in nested, dynamic Dictionary<String, Any> recursively

Tags: swift, dictionary, recursion, closures

In a given Dictionary, I need to find a nested Dictionary (`[String : Any]`) for a given key.

The general structure of the Dictionary (e.g. nesting levels, value types) is unknown and given dynamically. [1]

Inside of this sub-Dictionary, there is a given value for the key "value" (don't ask) which needs to be fetched.

Here's an example:

```
let theDictionary: [String : Any] =
  [ "rootKey" :
    [ "child1Key" : "child1Value",
      "child2Key" : "child2Value",
      "child3Key" :
        [ "child3SubChild1Key" : "child3SubChild1Value",
          "child3SubChild2Key" :
              [ "comment" : "child3SubChild2Comment", 
                 "value" : "child3SubChild2Value" ]
        ],
      "child4Key" :
        [ "child4SubChild1Key" : "child4SubChild1Value",
          "child4SubChild2Key" : "child4SubChild2Value",
          "child4SubChild3Key" :
            [ "child4SubChild3SubChild1Key" :
                [ "value" : "child4SubChild3SubChild1Value", 
                  "comment" : "child4SubChild3SubChild1Comment" ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
  ]
```

With brute force and pseudo memoization, I managed to hack a function together that iterates through the entire Dictionary and fetches the value for a given key:

```
func dictionaryFind(_ needle: String, searchDictionary: Dictionary<String, Any>) -> String? {

  var theNeedleDictionary = Dictionary<String, Any>()

    func recurseDictionary(_ needle: String, theDictionary: Dictionary<String, Any>) -> Dictionary<String, Any> {
      var returnValue = Dictionary<String, Any>()
      for (key, value) in theDictionary {
        if value is Dictionary<String, Any> {
          if key == needle {
            returnValue = value as! Dictionary<String, Any>
            theNeedleDictionary = returnValue
            break
          } else {
              returnValue =  recurseDictionary(needle, theDictionary: value as! Dictionary<String, Any>)
            }
        }
     }
     return returnValue
    }
  // Result not used
  _ = recurseDictionary(needle, theDictionary: searchDictionary)

  if let value = theNeedleDictionary["value"] as? String {
    return value
  }
  return nil
}
```

This works so far. (For your playground testing pleasure:

```
let theResult1 = dictionaryFind("child3SubChild2Key", searchDictionary: theDictionary)
print("And the result for child3SubChild2Key is: \(String(describing: theResult1!))")

let theResult2 = dictionaryFind("child4SubChild3SubChild1Key", searchDictionary: theDictionary)
print("And the result for child4SubChild3SubChild1Key is: \(String(describing: theResult2!))")

let theResult3 = dictionaryFind("child4Key", searchDictionary: theDictionary)
print("And the result for child4Key is: \(String(describing: theResult3))")
```

).

My question here:

What would be a more clean, concise, "swifty", way to iterate through the Dictionary and - especially - break completely out of the routine as soon the needed key has been found?

Could a solution even be achieved using a Dictionary extension?

Thanks all!

[1] A KeyPath as described in [Remove nested key from dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40261857/remove-nested-key-from-dictionary) therefor isn't feasible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A more compact recursive solution might be:

```
func search(key:String, in dict:[String:Any], completion:((Any) -> ())) {
    if let foundValue = dict[key] {
        completion(foundValue)
    } else {
        dict.values.enumerated().forEach {
            if let innerDict = $0.element as? [String:Any] {
                search(key: key, in: innerDict, completion: completion)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the usage is:

```
search(key: "child3SubChild2Key", in: theDictionary, completion: { print($0) })
```

which gives:

```
["comment": "child3SubChild2Comment", "value": "child3SubChild2Subchild1Value"]
```

---

alternatively, if you don't want to use closures, you might use the following:

```
extension Dictionary {
    func search(key:String, in dict:[String:Any] = [:]) -> Any? {
        guard var currDict = self as? [String : Any]  else { return nil }
        currDict = !dict.isEmpty ? dict : currDict

        if let foundValue = currDict[key] {
            return foundValue
        } else {
            for val in currDict.values {
                if let innerDict = val as? [String:Any], let result = search(key: key, in: innerDict) {
                    return result
                }
            }
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

usage is:

```
let result = theDictionary.search(key: "child4SubChild3SubChild1Key")
print(result) // ["comment": "child4SubChild3SubChild1Comment", "value": "child4SubChild3SubChild1Value"]
```

Comment: Thanks very much Andrea! Much clearer to read. I tested your code, which is working fine in regards of printing out the sub-Dictionary content. 

The thing here is, that I can't figure out how to use the completion handler passing the inner dictionary so I can extract the value (preferably with subscript notation) without passing a return value. Would be great if you could extend your usage example so that at least the sub-Dictionary could be further used.

Comment: @andrea-mugnani Apologies for not being clear. What I'd like most would be an extension func of Dictionary where I just had to say 
'let myResultValue = myDictionary.getNestedValue(forKey: "mySpecialKey")' . This should search the Dictionary recursively., If it finds the Dictionary for the key, it should take the value for the underlying key "value" (confusing naming, I know). But just your search function that'd allow me to get back the Dictionary for former use would be fine - I just have no clue how to break out of the completion handler here :-|

Comment: Hi @andrea-mugnaini - I really appreciate your work - thank you so much. Tried it in Playground with the dictionary given above and this code:
'let result = theDictionary.search(key: "child4SubChild3SubChild1Key")
print("\(String(describing: result))")' but the result was nil, instead it should be '[ "value" : "child4SubChild3SubChild1Value", "comment" : "child4SubChild3SubChild1Comment" ]' - in this case of test-print, but in regards of the API, it should be the sub-Dictionary. Sorry for being so unclear.

Comment: Hi @andrea-mugnaini - in Playground, I get an error 'error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT).
The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.
' when executing your first solution code, which for whichever reason I did not see before. Just to let you know :)

Comment: @gresch Fixed the error message on Solution 1: clearly it's a playground bug, to solve the message I just Introduced: `dict.values.enumerated`. Solution 2 working as expected. If you have any concerns, let me know.

Comment: Hi @andrea-mugnaini - thank you very much - this works as expected. To find the final value I just need to wrap your search extension func. It's now clear and concise and seems also quite robust thanks to the initial guard condition. I gladly accept this as a valid answer and thank you again for this nice little gem of software craftsmanship :) I think others stumbling upon this problem, will like your code, too!

Comment: If anyone is interested in the performance, the non-block version is faster: 41640  vs 933150 ns for 1 run, 3357 vs 5117 ns avg for 10000 runs. Tested with foundation benchmark.

Answer (score 0):

The following extension can be used for finding values of a key in nested dictionaries, where different levels each can contain the same key associated with a different value.

```swift
extension Dictionary where Key==String {
    func find<T>(_ key: String) -> [T] {
        var keys: [T] = []
        
        if let value = self[key] as? T {
            keys.append(value)
        }
        self.values.compactMap({ $0 as? [String:Any] }).forEach({
            keys.append(contentsOf: $0.find(key))
        })
        
        return keys
    }
}
```