# How to update a value in a nested dictionary given path fragment in Swift?

Tags: swift, dictionary, inout

I have a nested dictionary and an array containing path fragment. I need to update the value at that location.

I am possibly looking for a recursive function instead of extensions to `Dictionary` types and such.

I am not able to do this recursively because I making a copy of the `inout` param.

```
var dict: [String: Any] = ["channel": ["item": ["title": 1111]]]
var pathFrag = ["channel", "item", "title"]
var val = 123

func addAt(pathFrag: inout [String], val: Int, data: inout [String: Any]) {
    if let first = pathFrag.first {
        if let item = data[first] {
            print(item)
            pathFrag.remove(at: 0)
            if !pathFrag.isEmpty {
                var d: [String: Any] = data[first] as! [String: Any]
                print("e: \(d)")
                return addAt(pathFrag: &pathFrag, string: string, data: &d)
            } else {
                data[first] = val
                print("else: \(data)")  // ["title": 123]
            }
        }
    }
}


addAt(pathFrag: &pathFrag, val: val, data: &dict)
print(dict)
```

How to update the value of `title` to `123`?

Comment: It would be better not to use inout at all. Now you can recurse in a helper function that returns the final value.

Comment: I was a bit concerned when the dictionary is large and making copies would take a performance hit.

Comment: Understood but you can’t have your cake and eat it too. If you want this recursive algorithm, it seems to me foolish to throw away the advantage of value types that allow you to reason clearly and write just the kind of algorithm you want. And premature optimization is always, uh, premature.

Comment: Also I would point out that this entire notion is unSwifty. The use of Any is a bad smell. In Objective-C this would be one-liner thanks to KVC and keypaths.

Comment: @matt How to do it using Objective-C? I tried `var d = dict as NSDictionary; d.setValue(123, forKeyPath: "channel.item.title");`, but it is giving `SIGABRT`.

Comment: Because you have to have nested NSMutableDictionaries to do it. But I would question the entire data structure here. What are you _really_ trying to do, standing ten feet back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `var d: [String: Any] = data[first] as! [String: Any]` makes a copy of `data[first]` and not a reference to it like `&` and `inout`. So, when `addAt(pathFrag: &pathFrag, string: string, data: &d)` is called, only `d` is changed. To make this change reflect on the original `data[first]`, you have to assign `d` back to `data[first]`.

Do this:

```
var dict: [String: Any] = ["channel": ["item": ["title": 1111]]]
var pathFrag = ["channel", "item", "title"]

func addAt(pathFrag: inout [String], data: inout [String: Any]) {
    if let first = pathFrag.first {
        if let item = data[first] {
            pathFrag.remove(at: 0)
            if !pathFrag.isEmpty {
                var d: [String: Any] = data[first] as! [String: Any]
                addAt(pathFrag: &pathFrag, data: &d)
                data[first] = d
            } else {
                data[first] = 123
            }
        }
    }
}


addAt(pathFrag: &pathFrag, data: &dict)
print(dict)
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to make this tail recursive. The assignment `data[first] = d` comes after the function call `addAt` which can lead to stackoverflow.

Comment: Yes, indeed, it can me made recursive. But I assumed it would somewhat defeat the purpose of changing `data` by its reference. You could do `data[first] = addAt(pathFrag: &pathFrag, data: &d)` in the `if` block, add `return data[first]` in the `else`, and `return data` outside of the outermost `if`.

Comment: `var d: [String: Any] = data[first] as! [String: Any]` will cause a crash if you use a new key in `pathFrag`. eg. `["channel", "name", "title"]`

Answer (score 3):

This is not what you asked, but the entire premise here is unSwifty. The use of `[String:Any]` is a Bad Smell. It seems more like Objective-C. And indeed this whole thing is a one-liner in Objective-C:

```
NSMutableDictionary * d1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary: @{ @"title" : @1111 }];
NSMutableDictionary * d2 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary: @{ @"item" : d1 }];
NSMutableDictionary * d3 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary: @{ @"channel" : d2 }];
```

Okay, that was just to prepare the data. Here’s the one-liner:

```
[d3 setValue:@123 forKeyPath:@"channel.item.title"];
```

But I would question the entire nested dictionaries concept; it seems to me you’ve gone down a wrong well here and you need to stand back and rethink your data structure.

Comment: I am parsing XML constructing a dictionary out of it. I think it would be better to use class/struct to represent the data instead of dictionary then.

Comment: There are XML parsing classes. I’ve explained elsewhere how to use them. Assuming you know the expected structure, you should be using nested structs if possible.

Comment: See https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/master/bk2ch23p818xml/ch36p1070xml

Answer (score 0):

```swift
extension Dictionary {
    subscript(jsonDict key: Key) -> [String:Any]? {
        get {
            return self[key] as? [String:Any]
        }
        set {
            self[key] = newValue as? Value
        }
    }
}

// For your case
dict[jsonDict: "channel"]?[jsonDict: "item"]?["title"] = 123
```

Refer to:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41543070/9315497

https://talk.objc.io/episodes/S01E31-mutating-untyped-dictionaries