# Swift: How to set a value in a Dictionary at a given sublevel?

Tags: swift, dictionary

Given this dictionary as an example:

```
var d = ["a": ["b": ["c": 30, "d": 20] ] ]
```

I would like to write a function that could add/update a value into this dictionary.

First example, if I call :

```
d.set(40, at: ["a", "b", "c"])
```

The function would progressively go into key `a`, then `b`, then `c`, and transform this dictionary into:

```
var d = ["a": ["b": ["c": 40, "d": 20] ] ]
```

Now if I call this instead:

```
d.set(60, at: ["a", "e", "f"])
```

I would like to get this dictionary instead:

```
var d = ["a": ["b": ["c": 40, "d": 20] ], "e": ["f": 60] ]
```

Could you help me writing this function?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Maybe off topic but: Can be that a better approach would be to use objects to represents your object instead of a dictionary ?

Comment: The real problem IMHO is that this is not a good idea. You could either use NSDictionary and Cocoa key paths, or you could use Swift nested structs and Swift key paths.

Comment: See for example the discussion at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55198324/how-to-update-a-value-in-a-nested-dictionary-given-path-fragment-in-swift

Comment: Basically I question why you think you need to do this in the first place. Can you explain what you are _really_ trying to do?

Comment: The CPU that would be required to do this would be immense. Can you explain your purpose? I'm thinking accomplishing this would be very tricky.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to do the trick:

**Edit** Now this covers all the provided uses cases

```
extension Dictionary where Value == Any {
    mutating func set<V>(_ value: V, at keyPath: [Key]) {
        var keyPath = keyPath
        guard !keyPath.isEmpty else { return }
        let topLevel = keyPath.removeFirst()
        guard !keyPath.isEmpty else {
            self[topLevel] = value
            return
        }
        guard keyPath.count > 1 else {
            self = merge(with: [topLevel: [keyPath.last!: value]])
            return
        }
        let leafKey = keyPath.removeLast()
        let nested = [leafKey: value].nest(in: keyPath)
        guard let child = self[topLevel] as? [Key: Any] else {
            self[topLevel] = nested
            return
        }
        
        self = self.merge(with: [topLevel: child.merge(with: nested)])
    }
    
    func merge(with other: [Key: Any] ) -> [Key: Any] {
        var result = self
        
        for key in other.keys {
            if !keys.contains(key) {
                result[key] = other[key]
            } else {
                switch (self[key], other[key]) {
                case let (lhs, rhs) as ([Key: Any], [Key: Any]):
                    result[key] = lhs.merge(with: rhs)
                default:
                    result[key] = other[key]
                }
            }
        }
        return result
    }
    
    func nest(in keys: [Key]) -> [Key: Any] {
        let initial: [Key: Any] = self as [Key: Any]
        let result: [Key: Any] = keys.reversed().reduce(into: initial) { result, key in
            result = [key: result]
        }
        return result
    }
}



var d: [String: Any] = ["a": ["b": ["c": 30, "d": 20] ] ] // ["a": ["b": ["c": 30, "d": 20]]]
d.set(40, at: ["a", "b", "c"]) // ["a": ["b": ["c": 40, "d": 20]]]
d.set(60, at: ["a", "e", "f"]) // ["a": ["b": ["c": 40, "d": 20], "e": ["f": 60]]]
d.set(["f": 42], at: ["a", "d"]) // ["a": ["b": ["c": 40, "d": 20], "e": ["f": 60], "d": ["f": 42]]]
```